# Url parameter in express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Im building a basic web app with node/express and mongoose. How do i replace :id in express parameter to a string

For example

mongoose model

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Let say there is a user name `"Mr robot king"` in the User's collection right now

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, user) {
       res.render('home');
    });
});
```

result of the url

```
localhost:8080/5asdasd43241asdasdasd
```

What i want is

```
localhost:8080/Mr-robot-king
```

Answer (score 3):

In essence, that wouldn't be too difficult:

```
app.get('/:name', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.params.name.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  User.findOne({ name : name }, function(err, user) {
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

Some considerations:

- Since your example replaces spaces with hyphens, and the code above does the opposite, user names with actual hyphens in them will break this substitution scheme;
- If user names are allowed to contain characters that have special meaning in URL's (like `&` or `?`), when building the links, you should encode them. So the user name `jill&bob` will yield the link `localhost:8080/jill%26bob`
- You probably want to add an [index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) to the `name` field to make sure that queries are fast;

**EDIT**: to generate these links, for instance from an EJS template, you can use something like this:

```
<a href="/<%= user.name.replace(/ /g, '-') %>">go to page</a>
```

Comment: I did it , but still it keeps showing the percentage, `GET /Mr%20Robot%20King%`

Comment: If you take a look at this web page, url it has hyphens, and Im not really sure why express doesn't have this option where it will change multiple strings into hypens format

Comment: @sinusGob if the links are showing percentages, it means that you're not actually replacing spaces with hyphens when creating the links. But that's out of the scope of this question tbh, because it depends on how you are creating your HTML. Express has nothing to do with how the links in your HTML look, you have to build such functionality yourself.

Comment: So technically before i save `Mr robot king` to the database I have to add hyphens, so that it would store `Mr-robot-king`?

Comment: @sinusGob No. When, in the HTML, the links to `localhost:8080/user-name` are generated, you need to replace spaces with hyphens. However, this entirely depends on _how_ you are generating your HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to ask you something, how do i do it only one time? because imagine if i have a lot URLS that require `<%= user.name.replace(/ /g, '-')` this line of code. Can i just do i it one time like in a middleware or something?

Comment: @sinusGob perhaps you should open a new question specifically for that. Perhaps people more familiar with EJS can help you out better.

Comment: and Btw , `<a href="/<%= user.name.replace(/ /g, '-') %>">go to page</a>` this code spawn some error, like `replace is undefined`

Comment: Just a quick question, what is a templating engine that is good for node.js besides EJS? Just asking your opinion

Comment: @sinusGob I like [`pug`](https://github.com/pugjs/pug), but that might be a bit of an acquired taste.

Comment: I heard pug/jade is slow compare to handlebars, ejs or mustache. Is it true?

Comment: @sinusGob no idea, tbh. I've never had issues with it.

Comment: It is working fine in now, replace does work, I didn't check my models attributes properly. But there is one more thing, if i use `replace.(/ /g, '-')` it will change `Mr robot king` -> `Mr-robot-king-` there is an extra hyphens. How do i remove the extra hyphen at the end?